# Do ultralights registered in Germany require an annual inspection?

Tags: ultralight, airworthiness, germany

I'm trying to find out how the German Ultralight aircraft ongoing inspections system works - do German registered Ultralight need to be inspected annually before they can then be operated for a further period?

Comment: Ultralights in Europe are not regulated by EASA, but nationally, so the `easa-regulations` tag does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The [»Verordnung zur Prüfung von Luftfahrtgerät (LuftGerPV)«](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/luftgerpv_2013/__13.html) states in §13 (1):

> Bei Luftsportgerät mit einer höchstzulässigen Leermasse über 120 Kilogramm hat der Halter das von der zuständigen Stelle festgelegte Instandhaltungsprogramm innerhalb der darin festgesetzten Fristen vollständig durchzuführen. **Zusätzlich wird das Luftsportgerät alle zwölf Monate einer Nachprüfung (Jahresnachprüfung) unterzogen.** Diese dient der Feststellung der Lufttüchtigkeit und der Überprüfung der Übereinstimmung mit den im zugehörigen Gerätekennblatt enthaltenen Angaben. Die Nachprüfung ist in einem Nachprüfschein zu bescheinigen. Eine Ausfertigung des Nachprüfscheins ist zu den Betriebsaufzeichnungen des Luftfahrtgeräts zu nehmen; eine Ausfertigung des jeweils letzten Nachprüfscheins ist im Luftfahrzeug mitzuführen.

The bold part confirms that the ultralight has to be inspected every 12 months.

Comment: Thanks Rocket Bag, that's exactly what I was after. 

Comment: @BradEdwardWagenhauser Instead of saying thank you in the comments, you should mark this answer as accepted. Have a look at the [tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how the site works.